# How do I change font weight of sibling elements when one is focused?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the font weight of some elements of different classes when the user focuses the text field (which is one of the elements), by using CSS only.

Relevant part of the HTML document:

```
<div id="field-entries">
    <div class="field"><span class="title-field">Item No.</span><input type="text" class="field-entry"></div>
    <div class="field"><span class="title-field">Item</span><input type="text" class="field-entry"></div>
    <div class="field"><span class="title-field">Qty</span><input type="text" class="field-entry"></div>
    <div class="field"><span class="title-field">Rate</span><input type="text" class="field-entry"></div>
    <div class="field"><span class="title-field">Discount</span><input type="text" class="field-entry"></div>
    <div class="field"><span class="title-field">Date</span><input type="date" class="field-entry"></div>
</div>
```

When the user focuses on an `input` element of class `field-entry` the the text in the corresponding `span` and `input` elements get bolder

How can I accomplish this with only CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) for that.

```css
form p:focus-within * { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<form>
    <p><label for="a">Item No.</label> <input id="a" value="foo"/></p>
    <p><label for="b">Item</label> <input id="b"  value="bar"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: That's how I would approach it as well. Except for use of paragraphs -- I would consider these ill-fit and also distracting in your answer (since they are of no particular importance to the original problem). A minor nitpick (I feel it's justified since I were penning a similar answer which I abandoned): you can't use *names* of elements for `for` attribute values -- these must be *identifiers*. I know, it sucks, but that's what [the spec says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-label-for).

Answer (score 1):

you can use :focus to apply style

```css
input.field-Entry:focus {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="Feild-Entries">
    <div class="feild"><span class="title-feild">Item No.</span><input type="text" class="field-Entry"></div>
    <div class="feild"><span class="title-feild">Item</span><input type="text" class="field-Entry"></div>
    <div class="feild"><span class="title-feild">Qty</span><input type="text" class="field-Entry"></div>
    <div class="feild"><span class="title-feild">Rate</span><input type="text" class="field-Entry"></div>
    <div class="feild"><span class="title-feild">Discount</span><input type="text" class="field-Entry"></div>
    <div class="feild"><span class="title-feild">Date</span><input id="Date" type="date" class="field-Entry"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague but I think the OP is wanting the preceding sibling span with class 'title-field' to also be bold.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, But You Have To Change The Position of span

```css
/* default link color is blue */
.feild span {
  font-weight: 400;
}

/* prev siblings should be red */

.feild input:focus, .feild input:focus + span {
  font-weight:800;
}
```

```html
<div id="Feild-Entries">
    <div class="feild"><input type="text" class="field-Entry"><span class="title-feild">Item No.</span></div>
    <div class="feild"><input type="text" class="field-Entry"><span class="title-feild">Item</span></div>

</div>
```